# Objective-C++ and .cpp files in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, class, objective-c++

I'm trying to make a simple Objective-C++ applicaiton.  All of my code is compiling fine, including the use of C++ in Objective-C classes, until I try and add a C++ class to the mix.  I've created a simple C++ class:

Test.h

```
class Test {

};
```

and included this file in a Objective-C class (with a .mm extension) and I get the following build error:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Test'
```

Clearly I'm missing some simple concept here.  I'd appreciate some enlightment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

helixed's answer will not help, your class will be just skiped by preprocessor if __cplusplus undefined.

Most of all you trying to include C++ class from *.m file, try to rename it to *.mm.
This solve the same problem on my side.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after scanning more closely over [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1), it looks like the answer to to use the `__cplusplus` preprocessor flag in the header file.  Here's what the code looks like now:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus

class Test {

};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the preprocessor command required be:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
```

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 6 there is the following option:

```
Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language -> Compile Sources As
```

You can set that to Objective-C++ and then the file extension does not matter. This is particularly useful if you are working cross-platform and need to use other file extensions.

Comment: Almost five years later, this was quite helpful! It let me know what setting to look for, even on a later version of xCode. As you say, working on a cross-platform native code app, I was not looking forward to having to rename all my .cpp files to .mm! Thanks so much!