# how to use ".mm .cpp" files with Objective c project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7, objective-c++

I have downloaded a static library `Example1`, which is a collection of files written with `.mm` and `.cpp` extensions .

My own static library `Example2` is written in Objective C and has `.m` file extensions.

How can I call the `Example1` library from the `Example2` library?

I have read some thing about using a header bridge, but I do not know what I should do exactly? Is there any way to use both libraries without a header bridge? Can any one show me how to do that with `Example1` and `Example2`?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28073090/885189

Comment: its not clear , can u help me more , because I'm beginner